# Parsing a content placeholder with PHP (regex)

Tags: php, regex

I have some content placeholders that appear in my content and always have this format:

```
[page_x]
```

Where x is an integer.

What I'd like to do is get all the placeholders that match that pattern so I can iterate through them.

I'm a real novice at regex (trying to learn) so all I have at this point is:

```
preg_match_all("/[page_(*)]/", $content, $matches)
```

Which is clearly wrong as it doesn't work - for instance a $content containing [page_1] gives me an empty array for $matches.

Any help, or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: * means repeated zero or more times, but you did not specify WHAT was repeated. change it to ([0-9]+)  which means number between 0 and 9, repeated 1 or more times

Comment: references: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html and http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: Thank you for the references. I really need to understand regex as I am sure it opens up a whole new world.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The square bracket has special meaning in regexes.  You need to escape it.  Also the `*` on its own is meaningless.

It is a modifier that means `zero or more of preceeding character` so you need a preceeding character  I've added a `.` here which will match anything

Lastly to prevent over-matches you need to add `?` to make the group match non-greedy

```
preg_match_all('/\[page_(.*?)\]/', $content, $matches)
```

If you are always going to match numbers (i.e page_1, page_2, page_3), the better regex woud be

```
preg_match_all("/\[page_(\d+)\]/", $content, $matches)
```

`\d+` means 1 or more digits

Comment: This solves the problem perfectly. Thank you so much.

I opted for the latter as I want to enforce the match to integers.

Comment: I have to wait another 30 seconds :)